# Batch renaming JPG filenames in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, unix, centos, batch, rename

I have about 80 of these files in my directory.

```
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 vagrant vagrant  38122 Nov 13 12:19 CRMPicco RFC16 Women's 80.jpg
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 vagrant vagrant 101286 Nov 13 12:19 CRMPicco RFC16 Women's 8.jpg
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 vagrant vagrant  30110 Nov 13 12:19 CRMPicco RFC16 Women's 9.jpg
```

I am running CentOS 7.0 and have rename installed.

```
[vagrant@crmpicco /var/www/crmpicco/web/php/upload/10111/165-190]# which rename
/usr/bin/rename

cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
```

However the following doesn't rename any files for me. I've tried a bunch of different ways seen on SuperUser, but none of them seem to work.

```
[vagrant@crmpicco /var/www/crmpicco/web/php/upload/10111/165-190]# rename s/Women/W/ *.jpg
```

Am I doing something stoopid?

Comment: What do you want to rename the files to?

Comment: @Wilf In my example above I wanted to start by renaming `Women` to `W`. Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how `rename` works. The util-linux "rename" command only accepts two static strings (basic search and replace):

```
rename "Women" "W" *.jpg
```

For the Perl-like regex syntax, you will need **`rename.pl`** aka **`perl-rename`**. It's not packaged for CentOS, but you can obtain it [directly from CPAN](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) as the `File::Rename` module

Some distros such as Debian will swap the names, so that `rename` is from Perl and `rename.ul` from util-linux, I guess that's where the confusion comes from.